# The Square Root of Two UITextFields

Tags: swift, uitextfield

I can't find a way to get the data from two UITextFields and display the root value in another. This is how far I’ve got:

```
@IBAction func squareRoot(_ sender: Any){
       cValue.text = String(Double(cValue.text!)! * Double(cValue.text!)!)
       dValue.text = String(Double(dValue.text!)! * Double(dValue.text!)!)
       var theSquare = dValue.text! + cValue.text!
       theRootValue.text! =  sqrt(theSquare)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use like this:

```
func getRootValue() {
        if let cText = cValue.text, let dText = dValue.text {
            if let doubleC = Double(cText), let doubleD = Double(dText) {
                let theSquare = sqrt((doubleC * doubleC) + (doubleD * doubleD))
                rootValue.text = "\(theSquare)"
            }
        }
    }

    @IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        getRootValue()
    }
```

in your version, you take the root of the string
**Update**
according to comment you need to write next method:

```
func getRoofArea() {
        if let rootText = rootValue.text, let rootDouble = Double(rootText), let eText = eValue.text, let eDouble = Double(eText) {
            roofArea.text = "\(eDouble * rootDouble * 2)"
        }
    }

    @IBAction func secondButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        getRoofArea()
    }
```

if your rootValue.text != nil, eValue.text != nil, and if its can converts to Double, in roofArea.text you can see result of its multiple multiplied to 2.
And ScreenShot

[image: Screenshot]

Any questions?

Comment: That works a treat thankyou - is there any easy way to get two decimal places in Swift 4

Comment: it's so simple, what can be easier?

Comment: Sergey could you tell me as I can't seem to work it out

Comment: roofArea.text = String(Double(rootValue.text!)! * Double(eValue.text!)! * 2)
                
                self.roofArea.text = String(format:"%.2f") If `I try to incorporate this line of code into the line above It crashes

Comment: @JeremyGriffin, I'm edited my answer and added to it new method. don't use force unwrap like this: Double(eValue.text!)!, use only optional, like if let or guard let. It will save you from crushes